# how to move an object from one array to another

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I understand that this topic has been done before but I wanted to bring it up again for a specific reason, I have a function designed to move an item from one array to another, removing the item from the array it was originally in, but whenever I test it, it doesnt seem to work

```
-(void) moveOpperand: (NSMutableArray *) moveFrom :(NSMutableArray *) moveTo{
    NSString *opperandObject = [moveFrom lastObject];
    if (opperandObject) {
    [moveTo addObject:moveFrom.lastObject];
        [moveFrom removeLastObject];
    }
}
```

the method above is called in this method

```
-(NSMutableArray *) giveHand: (NSMutableArray *) hand : (NSMutableArray *)refrenceDeck{

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        [self moveOpperand:refrenceDeck :hand];
    }
    return hand;
}
```

the error when testing seems to be located when I try to implement the currentHand method

```
-(NSMutableArray *) currentHand{
    if (_currentHand == nil) {

        self.currentHand = [self.myDeck giveHand:self.currentHand :self.myDeck.currentDeck];

    }
    return _currentHand;

}
```

Comment: how, specifically, does it not work?

Comment: Please state the problem. Why does it 'seem' not to work?

Comment: As Dustin said what is your goal and how is they not fulfilling it?

Comment: my goal was to remove an object from the movefrom and add it to the moveto, however it doesnt seem to modify either of the NSMutableArrays passed to it

Comment: Could you show the code where you're calling this?

Comment: I tried your code in a very simple case and it seems fine.  E.g.: `NSMutableArray *fromArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"The string", nil];
    NSMutableArray *toArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    [self moveOpperand:fromArray :toArray];`.

Comment: Are you passing in copies of the array?  As @RyanPoolos states, show your code.

Comment: After you've called the moveOpperand method, have you analyzed the contents of those arrays in the debugger?

Comment: after checking, it seems like the problem isnt with the first two methods, its with this currenthand method

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think here is a very very simple category that should do it for any object.

NSObject+Move.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (Move)

/*
 Returns true if it sucessfully moves the object between arrays.
 */
- (BOOL)moveFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayA toArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayB;

@end
```

NSObject+Move.m

```
#import "NSObject+Move.h"

@implementation NSObject (Move)

- (BOOL)moveFromArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayA toArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrayB
{
    if ([arrayA containsObject:self]) {
        [arrayA removeObject:self];
        [arrayB addObject:self];

        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you aren't setting the `_currentHand` variable to nil at the appropriate time, thus you may not have the correct current hand which may make it 'seem' like an issue with your array swapping.